# Why does adding an index increase the execution time in SQLite?

Tags: index, optimization, execution-plan, index-tuning, sqlite

I'll just show you an example. Here `candidates` is a table of 1000000 candidates from 1000 teams and their individual scores. We want a list of all teams and whether the total score of all candidates within each team is within the top 50.

(Note that all `CREATE TABLE results AS ...` statements are identical, and the only difference is the presence of indices. These tables are created (and dropped) to suppress the query results so that they won't make a lot of noise in the output.)

```
------------
-- Set up --
------------

.open delete-me.db    -- A persistent database file is required

.print ''
.print '[Set up]'

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS candidates;

CREATE TABLE candidates AS
WITH RECURSIVE candidates(team, score) AS (
    SELECT ABS(RANDOM()) % 1000, 1
    UNION
    SELECT ABS(RANDOM()) % 1000, score + 1
    FROM candidates
    LIMIT 1000000
)
SELECT team, score
FROM candidates;


-------------------
-- Without Index --
-------------------

.print ''
.print '[Without Index]'

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS results;

ANALYZE;

.timer ON
.eqp   ON
CREATE TABLE results AS
WITH top_teams_verbose(top_team, total_score) AS (
    SELECT team, SUM(score)
    FROM candidates
    GROUP BY team
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
    LIMIT 50
),
top_teams AS (
    SELECT top_team
    FROM top_teams_verbose
)
SELECT team, SUM(team IN top_teams)
FROM candidates
GROUP BY team;
.eqp   OFF
.timer OFF


------------------------------
-- With Single-column Index --
------------------------------

.print ''
.print '[With Single-column Index]'

CREATE INDEX candidates_idx_1 ON candidates(team);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS results;

ANALYZE;

.timer ON
.eqp   ON
CREATE TABLE results AS
WITH top_teams_verbose(top_team, total_score) AS (
    SELECT team, SUM(score)
    FROM candidates
    GROUP BY team
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
    LIMIT 50
),
top_teams AS (
    SELECT top_team
    FROM top_teams_verbose
)
SELECT team, SUM(team IN top_teams)
FROM candidates
GROUP BY team;
.eqp   OFF
.timer OFF


-----------------------------
-- With Multi-column Index --
-----------------------------

.print ''
.print '[With Multi-column Index]'

CREATE INDEX candidates_idx_2 ON candidates(team, score);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS results;

ANALYZE;

.timer ON
.eqp   ON
CREATE TABLE results AS
WITH top_teams_verbose(top_team, total_score) AS (
    SELECT team, SUM(score)
    FROM candidates
    GROUP BY team
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
    LIMIT 50
),
top_teams AS (
    SELECT top_team
    FROM top_teams_verbose
)
SELECT team, SUM(team IN top_teams)
FROM candidates
GROUP BY team;
.eqp   OFF
.timer OFF
```

Here is the output

```
[Set up]

[Without Index]
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN TABLE candidates
|--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
`--LIST SUBQUERY 3
   |--CO-ROUTINE 1
   |  |--SCAN TABLE candidates
   |  |--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
   |  `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
   `--SCAN SUBQUERY 1
Run Time: real 0.958 user 0.923953 sys 0.030911

[With Single-column Index]
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN TABLE candidates USING COVERING INDEX candidates_idx_1
`--LIST SUBQUERY 3
   |--CO-ROUTINE 1
   |  |--SCAN TABLE candidates USING INDEX candidates_idx_1
   |  `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
   `--SCAN SUBQUERY 1
Run Time: real 2.487 user 1.108399 sys 1.375656

[With Multi-column Index]
QUERY PLAN
|--SCAN TABLE candidates USING COVERING INDEX candidates_idx_1
`--LIST SUBQUERY 3
   |--CO-ROUTINE 1
   |  |--SCAN TABLE candidates USING COVERING INDEX candidates_idx_2
   |  `--USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
   `--SCAN SUBQUERY 1
Run Time: real 0.270 user 0.248629 sys 0.014341
```

While the covering index `candidates_idx_2` does help, it seems that the single-column index `candidates_idx_1` makes the query significantly slower, even after I ran `ANALYZE;`. It's only 2.5x slower in this case, but I think the factor can be made greater if you fine-tune the number of candidates and teams.

Why is it?

Comment: it looks like sqlite underestimates the impact of row lookups to get values of score column